# listings using tcolorbox package without Chapter and Section environment effects

Tags: listings, environments, tcolorbox, listingsutf8

I want to get `listings` using `tcolorbox` package but without counting `Chapter` and `Section` environments. See in MWE, I used `section` environment withing listings which effects the counter for following sections. Would highly appreciate if someone help me get  `listings` using `tcolorbox` package but without counting `Chapter` and `Section` environments. Thanks

---

### Output

---

[image]

---

### MWE

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}%



\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\blindtext

% Redefine the document environment within a group
\begingroup
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}

\begin{tcblisting}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!25,left=6mm,
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}}}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
   Welcome to \LaTeX.
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}

\endgroup

\section{Second Section}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shall only `section` in the listings be unnumbered or should the counting be according to listed `internal` document?

Comment: I want `chapter` and `section` environments in the `listings` should be numbered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stores the current section counter and restores it after the listing environment. Internally, the section counter is reset for the listings output purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}%



\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\blindtext

\newcounter{truesectioncounter}
\setcounter{truesectioncounter}{\number\value{section}}
\begingroup
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}
\setcounter{section}{0}


\begin{tcblisting}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!25,left=6mm,
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}}}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
   Welcome to \LaTeX.
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\setcounter{section}{\number\value{truesectioncounter}}

\endgroup

\section{Second Section}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Improved Version

This version stores all sectioning counters (parts....subparagraph) by the command `\PushCounterValues` just before the `tcblistings` environment starts and restore them afterwards.

This way, any *internal* section command will not corrupted the documents counter values.

This could be simplified, if a self defined `\newtcblistingsenvironment` would be used...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}%



\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%% Storage tool macros

\listgadd{\restorecounterlist}{} % Dummy list
\newcommand{\newbackupcounter}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \newcounter{backup#1}%
  }{}%
}%


\newcommand{\PushCounterValue}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \setcounter{backup#1}{\number\value{#1}}
    \setcounter{#1}{0}
  }{%
  }%
}%

\newcommand{\PushCounterValues}{%
\forlistloop{\PushCounterValue}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%


\newcommand{\PopCounterValue}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \setcounter{#1}{\number\value{backup#1}}%
    \setcounter{backup#1}{0}% For 'safety'
  }{}%
}%

\newcommand{\PopCounterValues}{%
\forlistloop{\PopCounterValue}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%


\AtBeginDocument{%
% Setup the counter lists and provide the backup counters
\forcsvlist{\listgadd{\restorecounterlist}}{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}%
\forlistloop{\newbackupcounter}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\subsection{Outer subsection Number one}

\subsection{Outer subsection Number two}


\blindtext

% Redefine the document environment within a group


\begingroup
\PushCounterValues% Push the counter values to the backup values
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}
\setcounter{section}{0}


\begin{tcblisting}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!25,left=6mm,
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}}}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
   Welcome to \LaTeX.
\subsection{ A test subsection}%
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\PopCounterValues% Restore the original counter values%

\endgroup

\section{Second Section}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MYaseen208: Ok, that's nice -- I will add a solution, which stores all section counter values (chapters,sections,subsections,etc...)

Comment: This works fine but does not work properly if numbered listings are used. The numbered listings will have wrong counters.

Comment: @MYaseen208: Your original listings didn't have numbers (You mean the tcblisting is numbered)?), so I could not know, that you want to use them. I'll take a look later on

Comment: I have a [follow up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197064/4821).