# Counters for Chapter and Section environments when using tcolorbox for listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, environments, bookmarks, tcolorbox

This is a followup question of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196835/4821). With my MWE I'm getting wrong `Listing numbers`, wrong `toc` (including Chapter and Section environments from listings) and wrong `bookmarks` in pdf `toc`. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

---

### MWE

---

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}


%Definition of New Environments
\tcbset{
texexp/.style={colframe=green!85!black, colback=red!5!white,
coltitle=red!50!yellow!3!black, left=6mm,
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}},
fonttitle=\small\textsc\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small},
example/.style 2 args={texexp,
title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #1},label={#2}},
}


\newtcblisting{texexp}[1]{texexp,#1}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{texexptitled}[3][]{%
example={#2}{#3},#1}

\newtcolorbox[use counter from=texexptitled]{texexptitledspec}[3][]{%
example={#2}{#3},#1}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}%



\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%% Storage tool macros

\listgadd{\restorecounterlist}{} % Dummy list
\newcommand{\newbackupcounter}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \newcounter{backup#1}%
  }{}%
}%


\newcommand{\PushCounterValue}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \setcounter{backup#1}{\number\value{#1}}
    \setcounter{#1}{0}
  }{%
  }%
}%

\newcommand{\PushCounterValues}{%
\forlistloop{\PushCounterValue}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%


\newcommand{\PopCounterValue}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \setcounter{#1}{\number\value{backup#1}}%
    \setcounter{backup#1}{0}% For 'safety'
  }{}%
}%

\newcommand{\PopCounterValues}{%
\forlistloop{\PopCounterValue}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%


\AtBeginDocument{%
% Setup the counter lists and provide the backup counters
\forcsvlist{\listgadd{\restorecounterlist}}{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}%
\forlistloop{\newbackupcounter}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{Outer subsection Number one}
\subsection{Outer subsection Number two}

\blindtext

% Redefine the document environment within a group
\begingroup
\PushCounterValues% Push the counter values to the backup values
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\begin{texexptitled}{Example}{mylab}
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter Test}
    \section{Section 334}
    Here, we use Example  with a title line.
\end{document}
\end{texexptitled}
\PopCounterValues% Restore the original counter values%

\endgroup

\chapter{New Chapter}
\section{New Section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

---

### Output

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your `\tableofcontents` is outside of `\begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: The problem is deep inside the way `tcolorbox` uses counters. I can't figure out quickly

Comment: My bad. Sorry for this @ChristianHupfer. Even putting `\tableofcontents` inside of `\begin{document}...\end{document}` has issues.

Comment: I think I got it, see the answer, but I can't do more checks right now, I am off for about three or four hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose to put the the structure saving commands into the lower part only. Such, the numbering of the `tcolorbox` is not affected.

To avoid the `tocs` and `bookmarks` problems, I suggest to deactivate `\addtocontents` and `\addcontentsline` as was done for `\documentclass`.

My answer creates a new option `protect structure` which contains all this stuff.

```
\tcbset{protect structure/.style={
  before lower={\begingroup%
    \PushCounterValues% Push the counter values to the backup values
    \renewenvironment{document}{}{}%
    \renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}%
    \renewcommand\addtocontents[2]{}%
    \renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}%
    \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{}%
    \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}%
    #1%
  },
  after lower={%
    \PopCounterValues% Restore the original counter values%
    \endgroup%
  }},
protect structure/.default=}
```

It takes a parameter where counter settings can be given; here:

```
protect structure={\setcounter{chapter}{0}}
```

Now, all together, we get:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}


%Definition of New Environments
\tcbset{
texexp/.style={colframe=green!85!black, colback=red!5!white,
coltitle=red!50!yellow!3!black, left=6mm,
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}},
fonttitle=\small\textsc\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small},
example/.style 2 args={texexp,
title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #1},label={#2}},
}


\newtcblisting{texexp}[1]{texexp,#1}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{texexptitled}[3][]{%
example={#2}{#3},#1}

\newtcolorbox[use counter from=texexptitled]{texexptitledspec}[3][]{%
example={#2}{#3},#1}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}%



\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%% Storage tool macros

\listgadd{\restorecounterlist}{} % Dummy list
\newcommand{\newbackupcounter}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \newcounter{backup#1}%
  }{}%
}%


\newcommand{\PushCounterValue}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \setcounter{backup#1}{\number\value{#1}}
    \setcounter{#1}{0}
  }{%
  }%
}%

\newcommand{\PushCounterValues}{%
\forlistloop{\PushCounterValue}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%


\newcommand{\PopCounterValue}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \setcounter{#1}{\number\value{backup#1}}%
    \setcounter{backup#1}{0}% For 'safety'
  }{}%
}%

\newcommand{\PopCounterValues}{%
\forlistloop{\PopCounterValue}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%


\AtBeginDocument{%
% Setup the counter lists and provide the backup counters
\forcsvlist{\listgadd{\restorecounterlist}}{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}%
\forlistloop{\newbackupcounter}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%


\tcbset{protect structure/.style={
  before lower={\begingroup%
    \PushCounterValues% Push the counter values to the backup values
    \renewenvironment{document}{}{}%
    \renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}%
    \renewcommand\addtocontents[2]{}%
    \renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}%
    \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{}%
    \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}%
    #1%
  },
  after lower={%
    \PopCounterValues% Restore the original counter values%
    \endgroup%
  }},
protect structure/.default=}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{Outer subsection Number one}
\subsection{Outer subsection Number two}

\blindtext

\begin{texexptitled}[protect structure={\setcounter{chapter}{0}}]{Example}{mylab}
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter Test}
    \section{Section 334}
    Here, we use Example  with a title line.
\end{document}
\end{texexptitled}

\chapter{New Chapter}
\section{New Section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas F. Sturm for your answer. Your provided code works fine except for TOC and Bookmars in TOC in pdf view. I also don't want to include chapters and sections appearing in listings to my TOC.

Comment: @MYaseen208 That's mysterious. I don't have such entries using the answer code... Could you double-check again with the answer code?

Comment: @MYaseen208 I've just added a deactivation of `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` which seems to be a good idea. But this is not connected to TOC and bookmarks.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Some off-topic comment -- I like your `tcolorbox` package and recommend it on many occasions where appropiate -- perhaps it would be a good idea to provide the possibility of listing LaTeX documents within the outer documents without much ado... of course, not any preamble command can be disabled etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have the fear that many things easily could go wrong if full documents are included. It can work with a simple preamble but many users may be disappointed if *their* special preamble does not work. Nevertheless, I will think about it.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: My idea is that all of the `\usepackage{}`... commands for the inner document have to specified (if not mutually exclusive) in the 'driver' document already, inside `\usepackage` will be dropped as was done `documentclass` to. Perhaps to easy? I don't know at the moment. There range of usability will be limited, say for inner document with another documentclass completely different to the outer one. Caveats remain, of course

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Off-topic - comment: Perhaps this might be of interest to you... I proposed a very preliminary solution with overlays etc, but I fail at the positioning. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198255/bclogo-page-breaks

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just added an answer to this :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `number within` option in the definition of `texexptitled` has to be set to `backupsection` or `\backupchapter` (perhaps better)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}


%Definition of New Environments
\tcbset{
texexp/.style={colframe=green!85!black, colback=red!5!white,
coltitle=red!50!yellow!3!black, left=6mm,
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}},
fonttitle=\small\textsc\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small},
example/.style 2 args={texexp,
title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #1},label={#2}},
}


\newtcblisting{texexp}[1]{texexp,#1}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=backupsection]{texexptitled}[3][]{%
example={#2}{#3},#1}

\newtcolorbox[use counter from=texexptitled]{texexptitledspec}[3][]{%
example={#2}{#3},#1}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}%



\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%% Storage tool macros

\listgadd{\restorecounterlist}{} % Dummy list
\newcommand{\newbackupcounter}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \newcounter{backup#1}%
  }{}%
}%


\newcommand{\PushCounterValue}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \setcounter{backup#1}{\number\value{#1}}
    \setcounter{#1}{0}
  }{%
  }%
}%

\newcommand{\PushCounterValues}{%
\forlistloop{\PushCounterValue}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%


\newcommand{\PopCounterValue}[1]{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
    \setcounter{#1}{\number\value{backup#1}}%
    \setcounter{backup#1}{0}% For 'safety'
  }{}%
}%

\newcommand{\PopCounterValues}{%
\forlistloop{\PopCounterValue}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%


\AtBeginDocument{%
% Setup the counter lists and provide the backup counters
\forcsvlist{\listgadd{\restorecounterlist}}{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}%
\forlistloop{\newbackupcounter}{\restorecounterlist}%
}%



\begin{document}



\tableofcontents
\mainmatter





\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{Outer subsection Number one}
\subsection{Outer subsection Number two}

\blindtext

% Redefine the document environment within a group
\begingroup
\PushCounterValues% Push the counter values to the backup values
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\begin{texexptitled}{Example}{mylab}
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter Test}
    \section{Section 334}
    Here, we use Example  with a title line.
\end{document}
\end{texexptitled}
\PopCounterValues% Restore the original counter values%

\endgroup

\chapter{New Chapter}
\section{New Section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @christianhupfer for your answer. Your provided code works fine except for TOC and Bookmars in TOC in pdf view. I also don't want to include chapters and sections appearing in listings to my TOC.

Comment: @MYaseen208: I had no time for doing that too... Use Thomas F. Sturm's answer. I am writing on a tablet, having no chance to test code etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer By the way: The push/pop counter idea of yours from former answers is clever :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: See my comment to your answer... you can readily use that code (and definitely improve it) for an extension of `tcolorbox`, perhaps? The push/pop counters can (must?) be extended for `table` and `figure` counters too, but there are so many environments from other packages, it would be impossible to include any counter by `premature` definition