# bclogo page breaks

Tags: formatting, page-breaking

I am using the Bclogo package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bclogo. I have created environments for lemmas and proofs with it. The proof was too big to fit on the bottom of the page, so it just inserted a page break and moved it to the next page (see image below). Is there a way to have it start on the page below the lemma and then continue on the next page rather than moving everything to the next page and leaving a large gap between?

I currently have the following commands set up in a different file and just call them in the document for typing the lemmas and proofs.

```
\newcounter{LemmaBoxCounter}
\newcommand{\lem}[1]{\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bclampe, noborder=true, couleurBarre=Red, couleurBord=Black, couleur=blue!20, arrondi = 0.2, epBarre=0]{Lemma \arabic{LemmaBoxCounter}}
\raggedright #1
\addtocounter{LemmaBoxCounter}{1}
\end{bclogo}}

\newcounter{ProofBoxCounter}
\renewcommand{\proof}[1]{\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bclampe, noborder=true, couleurBarre=Red, couleurBord=Black, couleur=orange!10, arrondi = 0.2, epBarre=3.5]{Proof \arabic{ProofBoxCounter}}
\raggedright #1 \qed
\addtocounter{ProofBoxCounter}{1}
\end{bclogo}}
```

[image: Page Break]

Comment: If `bclogo` package does not provide breakable environments, there will be no easy continuation of such an environment. My knowledge of French is very limited, but I'll try to read that documentation. Thanks for making this nice package prominent to me!

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I do not speak any French so I can't see if there is information in it about page breaks or not. Please let me know if you find out anything. I think it is a really nice package otherwise.

Comment: I found so far nothing on page breaks etc. Sorry. Page breaking within an environment is quite difficult. Perhaps, it is possible to achieve the same behaviour with the `tcolorbox` environment and additional decorations. `tcolorbox` environments are breakable

Comment: I'm not sure how to add in the little logos that bclogo uses for the tcolorbox. Any suggestions? I created the following command:

\newcounter{ExColorBoxCount}
\newcommand{\eg}[1]{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5!white,colframe=green!75!black,title=\textbf{Example \arabic{ExColorBoxCount}}] #1
\addtocounter{ExColorBoxCount}{1}
\end{tcolorbox}}

Comment: I will look tomorrow

Comment: Short error correction: I meant `page breaking within boxes` is difficult, not in general for environments.

Comment: Were you able to find anything, Christian?

Comment: Sorry, only a rudimentary solution, not what you might expect. I am very sure, Gonzalo Medina or Thomas Sturm (both users here) have more knowledge on this than me, especially regarding the `tikZ` part of it. I will post, as a starting point, it is not meant as the solution!

Comment: I noticed Thomas Sturm about this, perhaps he has some clue.

Answer (score 4):

I take over the relay from Christian Hupfer and give a `tcolorbox` based solution. I tried to mimicry the original macros to get an equivalent appearance. The main difference is that lemma and proof are now breakable boxes. I left out the `\qed` since I don't know what is used for that one.

The macros take an optional parameter (any `tcolorbox` option). E.g., use `\lem[label=MyLabel]{....}` to set a label for reference.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}%
\usepackage[skins,breakable,xparse]{tcolorbox}%

\DeclareTotalTColorBox[auto counter]{\lem}{ O{} m }
{ enhanced,breakable,
  boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,arc=2mm,toptitle=3mm,top=3mm,left=7mm,right=1mm,pad at break=2mm,
  colframe=blue!20!white,interior hidden,
  coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,title={Lemma~\thetcbcounter},
  overlay unbroken and first={\node at ([xshift=4mm,yshift=-5mm]frame.north west) {\bclampe};},
  #1}
  {\raggedright #2}

\DeclareTotalTColorBox[auto counter]{\proof}{ O{} m }
{ enhanced,breakable,
  boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,arc=2mm,toptitle=3mm,top=3mm,left=7mm,right=1mm,pad at break=2mm,
  colframe=orange!10!white,interior hidden,
  coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,title={Proof~\thetcbcounter},
  overlay unbroken and first={\node[inner sep=0pt] (logo) at ([xshift=4mm,yshift=-5mm]frame.north west) {\bclampe};
    \draw[red,line width=3.5pt] (logo) -- ([xshift=4mm,yshift=1.5mm]frame.south west);  },
  overlay middle and last={\draw[red,line width=3.5pt] ([xshift=4mm,yshift=-1.5mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=4mm,yshift=1.5mm]frame.south west); },
  #1}
  {\raggedright #2%\qed
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\section{First}

\lem{\blindtext[1]}

\proof{\blindtext[1]}

\lem{\blindtext[2]}

\proof{\blindtext[4]}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

- To number within the chapter, add `number within=chapter` to the initialization options of the boxes.
- To label an individual box, add `label=mylabel` to the option list of a lemma or proof.

Here is the code to show the application:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}%
\usepackage[skins,breakable,xparse]{tcolorbox}%

\DeclareTotalTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{\lem}{ O{} m }
{ enhanced,breakable,
  boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,arc=2mm,toptitle=3mm,top=3mm,left=7mm,right=1mm,pad at break=2mm,
  colframe=blue!20!white,interior hidden,
  coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,title={Lemma~\thetcbcounter},
  overlay unbroken and first={\node at ([xshift=4mm,yshift=-5mm]frame.north west) {\bclampe};},
  #1}
  {\raggedright #2}

\DeclareTotalTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{\proof}{ O{} m }
{ enhanced,breakable,
  boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,arc=2mm,toptitle=3mm,top=3mm,left=7mm,right=1mm,pad at break=2mm,
  colframe=orange!10!white,interior hidden,
  coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,title={Proof~\thetcbcounter},
  overlay unbroken and first={\node[inner sep=0pt] (logo) at ([xshift=4mm,yshift=-5mm]frame.north west) {\bclampe};
    \draw[red,line width=3.5pt] (logo) -- ([xshift=4mm,yshift=1.5mm]frame.south west);  },
  overlay middle and last={\draw[red,line width=3.5pt] ([xshift=4mm,yshift=-1.5mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=4mm,yshift=1.5mm]frame.south west); },
  #1}
  {\raggedright #2%\qed
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

Lemma~\ref{A} on page~\pageref{A}, followed by
Lemma~\ref{B} on page~\pageref{B}.

Also see Proof~\ref{pA} on page~\pageref{pA}
and Proof~\ref{pB} on page~\pageref{pB}.

\section{First}

\lem[label=A]{\blindtext[1]}

\proof[label=pA]{\blindtext[1]}

\lem[label=B]{\blindtext[2]}

\proof[label=pB]{\blindtext[4]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I should definitely learn TikZ ;-)

Comment: Great answer! How would I make the counter depend on the current chapter though? Such as "Lemma 1.3" where "1" is the current chapter?

Comment: @lukas.coenig Using `[auto counter,number within=chapter]` instead of `[auto counter]` should do the trick.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Sorry to bother again, but where do I have to put the label to get the correct reference to such a lemma? I tried virtually everything, but always get only a reference to the current section.

Comment: @lukas.coenig See my updated answer.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Works perfectly!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I certainly would if I could! ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Ah, you mean it! It's not my question, that's the problem...

Comment: @lukas.coenig: Oh, sorry, I thought you're the OP. Ok, forget my comments. I will delete it]

Answer (score 2):

### This is not a full solution, rather a starting point, due to lack of time and lack of knowledge on TikZ ;-)

I tried to use the `tcolorbox` breakable and overlay features and its `theorem` style to make the boxes. The logos from `bclogo` packages can be inserted, but I fail at the positioning them correctly. This leads to a right shift of the box content as well.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{bclogo}%
\usepackage[theorems,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}%


\begin{document}

\chapter{First}


\section{First}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{lem}{Lemma}%
{overlay={\bclampe},left=5pt,breakable,colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title after break={Lemma \csuse{the\tcbcounter} -- \raggedleft Continued}}{lem}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{proof}{Proof}{breakable,overlay={\bclampe},colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title after break={Proof \csuse{the\tcbcounter} -- \raggedleft Continued}}{prf}


\begin{lem}{On Brontosaurs}{}
\textbf{By Ann Elk (Misses)}

Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again on the other end.
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}{On Brontosaurs}{}
\textbf{By Ann Elk (Misses)}

See the excavations ;-)

\blindtext[4]%
\end{proof}



\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]