# How to make a template latex like this?

Tags: forms, exercises

I wana ask a question. How to make a template latex like this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198255/bclogo-page-breaks

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence well spotted that the `bclogo` package was used for creating the exercises in the picture! :)

Comment: @clemens: Yes, I remembered the logos and that I tried to answer a 'similar' question once (but failed, due to lack of knowledge regarding tikz stuff)

Comment: Alternatively, one could place a minipage inside a tikz node.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The two boxes can be designed with a number of packages: [`bclogo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bclogo), [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed), [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox); the one having the crayon decoration on the left corresponds to a predefined style from the `bclogo` package so I defined a new environment for this box using this package; for the other one, I decided to use `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{framedex}{
    boxrule=0.8pt,
    enhanced,
    colframe=Maroon,
    colback=white,
    arc=2pt,
    top=10pt,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2ex},
    boxed title style={
      colback=Maroon,
      arc=2pt,
    },
    title={The title},
}
\newenvironment{framedcrayon}[2][]
  {\begin{bclogo}[
    logo=\bccrayon,
    couleur=yellow!15,
    arrondi=0.1,
    couleurBord=Maroon,#1]{#2}
  }
  {\end{bclogo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{framedex}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedex}

\begin{framedcrayon}{Title}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedcrayon}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just as an example, here's the code required to produce both framed boxes just using `bclogo`:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{framedcrayon}[2][]
  {\begin{bclogo}[
    logo=\bccrayon,
    couleur=yellow!15,
    arrondi=0.1,
    couleurBord=Maroon,#1]{#2}
  }
  {\end{bclogo}}

\newenvironment{framedanswer}[2][]
  {\renewcommand\bcStyleTitre[1]{
    \hfill\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=Maroon,align=center,text=white,rounded corners=2pt,yshift=15pt] {\strut##1};\hfill}
    \renewcommand\logowidth{0pt}
   \begin{bclogo}[
    logo=\bccrayon,
    arrondi=0.1,
    epBarre=0,
    couleurBord=Maroon,#1]{#2}
  }
  {\end{bclogo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{framedanswer}{The title}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedanswer}

\begin{framedcrayon}{Title}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedcrayon}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to make a list of this boxes. Like to add for the questions / answers boxes a list of boxes at the end of the document?

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger Yes, Please feel free to open a new question about this.