# listof framedanswer (extension)

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents

According to this question [How to make a template latex like this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232317/how-to-make-a-template-latex-like-this/232359?noredirect=1#comment661871_232359)

I use this nice piece of code for my documentation system.

Goal is to have a list of framed answers (a list of questions and told, on which page this is in the list of, in best case I can click on the question otherwise on page to jump to the place where the question is located.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{framedcrayon}[2][]
  {\begin{bclogo}[
    logo=\bccrayon,
    couleur=yellow!15,
    arrondi=0.1,
    couleurBord=Maroon,#1]{#2}
  }
  {\end{bclogo}}

    % \newtheorem{xfeature}{feature}
    % \newcommand\listxfeaturesname{Liste of Features}
    % \newlistof{feature}{xfeature}{\listxfeaturesname}
    % \newcommand\qdescription[1]{%
      % \addcontentsline{xfeature}{feature}%
        % {\protect\makebox[2.5cm][l]{Feature~\thexfeature\hfill}#1}}
    % \newenvironment{mfeature}[1][]{\begin{xfeature}\qdescription{#1}}{\end{xfeature}}
    % \providecommand{\feature}[1]{%
        % \begin{mfeature}[#1]
        % #1
        % \end{mfeature} 
        % }


   % \newtheorem{xfanswer}{Fragen}
    % \newcommand\listxanswername{\protect\langanswers}
    % \newlistof{Fragen}{xfanswer}{\listxanswername}
    % \newcommand\qadescription[1]{%
      % \addcontentsline{xfanswer}{Fragen}%
        % {\protect\makebox[2.5cm][l]{Fragen~\thexfanswer\hfill}#1}} 

\newenvironment{framedanswer}[2][]
  {\renewcommand\bcStyleTitre[1]{
    \hfill\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=Maroon,align=center,text=white,rounded corners=2pt,yshift=15pt] {\strut##1};\hfill}
    \renewcommand\logowidth{0pt}
   \begin{bclogo}[
    logo=\bccrayon,
    arrondi=0.1,
    epBarre=0,
    couleurBord=Maroon,#1]{#2}
  }
  {\end{bclogo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{framedanswer}{The title}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedanswer}

% \listofframedanswer %<---
\end{document}
```

There is some code I experimented with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This allows forward and backward linking from question to answer and reversed, but requires that the order of answers matches the order of questions.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{framedquestion}

\usepackage{hyperref}



\newenvironment{framedcrayon}[2][]{%
  \phantomsection
  \refstepcounter{framedquestion}
  \begin{bclogo}[
    logo=\bccrayon,
    couleur=yellow!15,
    arrondi=0.1,
    couleurBord=Maroon,#1]{\protect\hypertarget{question::\number\value{framedquestion}}{#2} -- \protect\hyperlink{answer::\number\value{framedquestion}}{Answer}}
    \protect\addcontentsline{fac}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theframedquestion}#2}%
  }{%
  \end{bclogo}
}



\newenvironment{framedanswer}[2][]{%
  \refstepcounter{framedquestion}
  \renewcommand\bcStyleTitre[1]{%
    \hfill\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=Maroon,align=center,text=white,rounded corners=2pt,yshift=15pt] {\strut##1};\hfill}
%  \renewcommand\logowidth{0pt}%  Faulty???
  \begin{bclogo}[
    logo=\bccrayon,
    arrondi=0.1,
    epBarre=0,
    couleurBord=Maroon,#1]{\protect\hypertarget{answer::\number\value{framedquestion}}{#2} -- \protect\hyperlink{question::\number\value{framedquestion}}{Question}
      \protect\addcontentsline{fan}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theframedquestion}#2}%
      % 
    }
  }{%
  \end{bclogo}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofframedcrayons}{%
  \section*{Questions}
  \@starttoc{fac}
}

\newcommand{\listofframedanswer}{%
  \section*{Answers}
  \@starttoc{fan}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofframedcrayons %<---


\listofframedanswer %<---


\section{First}

\begin{framedcrayon}{One}
  Hello
\end{framedcrayon}

\begin{framedcrayon}{Two}
  Hello again
\end{framedcrayon}



\setcounter{framedquestion}{0}

\clearpage

\begin{framedanswer}{The title}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedanswer}

\clearpage

\begin{framedanswer}{Another answer}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedanswer}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Have some minor errors, but I will take this solution.

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger: Ok, thanks, please keep me informed!

Comment: I have developed a ugly template. Trying to make one only template for different document types and most possibilities to design document. As a consequence there are really many packages loaded. To find the error seems to me very time consuming. Currently the jump back to the directory wont work. But I won't care about this at the moment. thanks very much to your solution.