# listof framedanswer (extension 2)

Tags: tikz-pgf

According to the solution Christian gave me a few hours ago, I have to extend my question and be more acurate.

See the solution at the posting from Christian,

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{framedquestion}

\usepackage{hyperref}



\newenvironment{framedcrayon}[2][]{%
  \phantomsection
  \refstepcounter{framedquestion}
  \begin{bclogo}[
    logo=\bccrayon,
    couleur=yellow!15,
    arrondi=0.1,
    couleurBord=Maroon,#1]{\protect\hypertarget{question::\number\value{framedquestion}}{#2} -- \protect\hyperlink{answer::\number\value{framedquestion}}{Answer}}
    \protect\addcontentsline{fac}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theframedquestion}#2}%
  }{%
  \end{bclogo}
}



\newenvironment{framedanswer}[2][]{%
  \refstepcounter{framedquestion}
  \renewcommand\bcStyleTitre[1]{%
    \hfill\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=Maroon,align=center,text=white,rounded corners=2pt,yshift=15pt] {\strut##1};\hfill}
%  \renewcommand\logowidth{0pt}%  Faulty???
  \begin{bclogo}[
    logo=\bccrayon,
    arrondi=0.1,
    epBarre=0,
    couleurBord=Maroon,#1]{\protect\hypertarget{answer::\number\value{framedquestion}}{#2} -- \protect\hyperlink{question::\number\value{framedquestion}}{Question}
      \protect\addcontentsline{fan}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theframedquestion}#2}%
      % 
    }
  }{%
  \end{bclogo}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofframedcrayons}{%
  \section*{Questions}
  \@starttoc{fac}
}

\newcommand{\listofframedanswer}{%
  \section*{Answers}
  \@starttoc{fan}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofframedcrayons %<---


\listofframedanswer %<---


\section{First}

\begin{framedcrayon}{One}
  Hello
\end{framedcrayon}

\begin{framedcrayon}{Two}
  Hello again
\end{framedcrayon}



\setcounter{framedquestion}{0}

\clearpage

\begin{framedanswer}{The title}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedanswer}

\clearpage

\begin{framedanswer}{Another answer}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedanswer}


\end{document}
```

The solution should be.
(1) No link between question and answer.
(2) framedcrayon environment without hyperref
(3) an listofcommand which only lists framedanswer.
(4) the link is only between the listof items and the item itself on the page where it is located.

framedanswer should be usable alone.

reason: I tried to modify the solution that it meets my needs and I failed.

If I want to have a question, it would be the question in title of framedanswer, the answer itselfs is inside the box.

Hope this information is specific enough....

Comment: you mean this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275159/71471

Comment: exactley, missed to add this link to the topic.

Comment: Apparently the first question wasn't clear enough and the solution went to another direction ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did not wanted to blame you. In fact it was a very low quality of asking therefor, I agree that it was my fault only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to private communications with the OP, a solution without the `bclogo` package is preferred. The following rebuilds the boxes using `tcolorbox`. Still, the very nice graphics from `bclogo` is used without loading that package.

Hopefully, the requirements are fulfilled:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newtcolorbox{framedcrayon}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  colback=yellow!15,
  colframe=Maroon,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
  boxrule=0.3mm,arc=1mm,boxsep=0pt,left=7mm,
  title={#2},
  attach title to upper={\par\smallskip},
  underlay={
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (logo) at ([xshift=4mm,yshift=-4mm]frame.north west) {\includegraphics[width=6mm]{bc-crayon}};
    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (logo) -- ([yshift=1mm]logo|-frame.south);
  },
  #1
}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter,list inside=myfan,list type=section]{framedanswer}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  colback=white,
  colframe=Maroon,
  coltitle=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  boxrule=0.3mm,arc=1mm,boxsep=0pt,left=7mm,
  title={#2},
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-0.15mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  boxed title style={enhanced,interior hidden,size=small},
  underlay={
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (logo) at ([xshift=4mm,yshift=-4mm]frame.north west) {\includegraphics[width=6mm]{bc-crayon}};
  },
  #1
}


\makeatletter

\newcommand{\listofframedanswer}{%
  \tcblistof[\section*]{myfan}{Answer}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\listofframedanswer

\section{First}

\begin{framedcrayon}{One}
  Hello
\end{framedcrayon}

\begin{framedcrayon}{Two}
  Hello again
\end{framedcrayon}


\clearpage

\begin{framedanswer}{The title}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedanswer}


\clearpage

\begin{framedanswer}{Another answer}
\lipsum[4]
\end{framedanswer}

\end{document}
```